# How to subtract 90 days

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to run a report for the Start Date being 90 days prior to the End Date (cell B5)

The End Date is a formula as well...
=eomonth(today(),-1)

Ideally what I want is:
If I ran the Report on May 6, 2020
I want the report End Date of April 30, 2020
Start date would be 90 days prior to April 30

Can anyone assist me with what the formula in the Start Date field should be?

Comment: Hey, maybe a dumb suggestion but did you try : `=B5 - 90` ?

Comment: Welcome. _I want the report End Date of April 30, 2020 Start date would be 90 days prior to April 30_ - Exactly what date would this be?